# Conflicting type and variable naming in C

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I recently stumbled on a weird code construct that lead the C compilers to a strange state. I would like to have an explanation why it occurs.

Here is my small code snippet that demonstrate the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int type_t;

int main (void)
{
  int a = 10, b = 100;

  type_t *type_t = &a; // We name a variable with type name
  type_t *type_c = &b; // We define a variable with type_t

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is the error message displayed by `gcc`:

```
#> gcc -Wall -Wextra -o sample sample.c 
sample.c: In function ‘main’:
sample.c:11:11: error: ‘type_c’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘type_t’?
   type_t *type_c = &b;
           ^~~~~~
           type_t
sample.c:11:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Or, with `clang`:

```
#> clang -Wall -Wextra -o sample sample.c 
sample.c:11:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'type_c'; did you mean 'type_t'?
  type_t *type_c = &b;
          ^~~~~~
          type_t
sample.c:10:11: note: 'type_t' declared here
  type_t *type_t = &a;
          ^
sample.c:11:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('type_t *' (aka 'int *') and 'type_t *')
  type_t *type_c = &b;
  ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Note that if we modify the code as follow, it compiles fine:

```
int main (void)
{
  int a = 10, b = 100;

  type_t *type_c = &b; // We define a variable with type_t
  type_t *type_t = &a; // We name a variable with type name

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, my question now!

It seems that the error is produced by the fact that the l-value of the assignation operator '=' is mistaken as a multiplication between `type_t` and `type_c`. As `type_c` is unknown, it explains the error message.

But, why do we have this confusion on an l-value ? Should not it be unambiguous that the `type_t` refer to the type and not the variable ?

I guess this is not an implementation problem as, both, `gcc` and `clang` behave the same. But, I really would like to have the key of this problem.

Comment: Confirming that MSVC 2017 also reproduces this behavior

Comment: MSVC 2008 complains with
    ... error C2377: 'type_t' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any 
other symbol
    .... see declaration of 'type_t'
    .... error C2065: 'type_c' : undeclared identifier

Comment: So, it must be part of C standard... But, why ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is expected and correct behaviour.  In C, there are a number of [namespaces](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3): labels, members, tags, and ordinary identifiers.  A `typedef` name is in the ordinary identifiers name space, as are variable names.

You have:

```
type_t *type_t = &a; // We name a variable with type name
type_t *type_c = &b; // We define a variable with type_t
```

There are three `type_t` occurrences here.  The first is the typedef name; no problem.  The second is a new variable name; no problem, but it hides (shadows) the typedef name; you can no longer refer to the type `type_t` in the current block of code.  The third occurrence refers to the variable; you are multiplying an integer pointer by an undefined variable (and trying to use the result as an l-value to receive the address of `b`), which is wrong on many levels.

When you reverse the order of those lines, it works fine because `type_c` is declared to be a `type_t *` OK; then `type_t` is defined to be a variable of type `type_t *`, but no further references can be made to the type `type_t` in the current block (any such reference is to the variable, not the type).

Note that if the `typedef` was inside the function, you'd not be able to shadow it with `type_t *type_t = &a;`.  See C11 [§6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1).